# What is the resource unit usage on Sharepoint Power Automate Triggers?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, connection, resource-throttling, trigger

I'm trying to work out how many resource units we are consuming using a power automate trigger in our flow, so we can avoid throttling as best as we can, but I find the documentation available doesn't help me understand resource unit usage of a PA sharepoint connection / trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online

My questions are, how many resource units does a trigger cost? And how much does the SP connection cost if anything? I figure because the connection is via a user account, it doesn't count as an "app-only authentication" which is limited to 25 requests per minute before throttling, correct me if i'm wrong.

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

David